# Where to ask questions related to network software?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I don't know where to ask questions related to network software. I actually needed to know whether there is any software like Virtual Hotspot. I need to do little bit testing with router. The thing I am looking for is similar to the one done in Virtual Box.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific to get a useful site recommendation.

Comment: So you're looking for a product recommendation?  Those are off topic through the entire SE network.

Comment: Yes, but it's Ok thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The correct place to ask is in *chat* not in a question.

Externally, I've sometimes use http://www.alternative.to/search?q=virtual+hotspot, but in this case, it wouldn't help.

My guess is that the chat rooms associated with Server Fault would be most fruitful, but the truth is this is something you discuss, not answer.

Per this seminal blog post [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), questions that ask for a recommendation are inherently off-topic.  Stack Overflow exists to answer questions definitively and reproducibly.  Shopping list recommdations do not lend themselves to answerability, and tend to denigrate into popularity contests.